# Ошибка 404 при поддомене

Tags: http-status-code-404, .htaccess, php

Решил сделать поддомен для тестирования новых функций сайта (beta.sity.ru), залил туда движок и теперь при попытки зайти на профиль юзера (beta.sity.ru/login) выдает ошибку 404

> The requested URL
> /var/www/sity/data/www/beta.sity.ru/index.php
> was not found on this server.

.htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,25})$ index.php?require_login=$1
```

Comment: Проверьте, какая у вас базовая директория для поддомена. По ходу апач ищет скрипт здесь: /var/www/sity/data/www/beta.sity.ru/

Исправьте пути или положите ваш "движок" в эту папку

Comment: Все верно. 
beta.sity.ru и sity.ru лежат в одной папке, путь в ошибке правильный

Comment: Права доступа на папку тоже верные? у апача есть доступ?